# How to automatically backup a SQL Server database on my ISP's location from my own pc?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have very limited access to the SQL Server at my ISP.

I have a very simple tool to create databases and execute SQL (which is enough most of the time) but now I also want to backup (and in the case of an accident, restore) a database from my own PC (or via a web application, if that's possible, both are ok)

Is there a tool which can do that auotmatically?

It's a SQL Server 2008 database.

I guess I can do it from my SQL Server Management Studio, but I'd prefer a tool that can do it scheduled.

Kind regards,
Michel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only backup (and restore) your database from local drives on the SQL Server machine - e.g. the machine at your ISP's location.

You **cannot** backup SQL Server and store the *.bak file on your local system, over the internet.

So what you need to do is create some kind of a process that stores the BAK file on the server machine at your ISP's location, and then copies or moves it to your home machine. For that, you need to have write access to some physical drive at your ISP on their SQL Server.